# I want to remove a given character of the first occurance from the string after the given index of the string

Tags: javascript, string

I want to remove a given character of the first occurance from the string after the given index of the string in javascript. Please help me out with the code.
Suppose, I have a string

```
str= "abcdabceabcde";
```

given index is 2
and given character is a,
so our output should be `abcdbceabcde`
`'a'` will be removed out from the string after the index 2 but after that no `'a'`s will be removed out.

Comment: Please add your first approach. Otherwise we'd do the whole work.

Comment: Why should we do your homework?

Comment: Have you looked at the description of `indexOf`? It allows you to specify where to start looking, what more do you need?

Comment: How could u assume that its my homework?

Comment: Because it doesn't seem to match any real world application, it's the kind of artificial problem that teachers assign.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I know that but how it would help me out?

Comment: I think you are not in the software development team..Should I mention the whole project what I am doing here.

Comment: `str.indexOf('a', 2)` will tell you the position of the first `a` after given index `2`. You can then use `substr` to get the parts of the string before and after this. What more do you need?

Comment: @user3264956: nobody is asking you to share your entire project. The purpose of Stack Overflow is to help you with the code you've written, not write it all for you from scratch.  Try and solve the problem yourself and then edit the code you've tried into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var input  = 'abcdabceabcde',
    search = 'a',
    index  = 2,
    pos = input.indexOf(search, index),
    output = input.substr(0, pos) + input.substr(pos+1);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var str = "abcdabceabcde";
var a = str.indexOf("a", 2);
var start = str.substring(0, a);
var end = str.substring(a+1);
var output = st+end;
```